# Relative Layout of ImageViews in multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

We're developing an app which includes a RelativeLayout containing multiple ImageViews that conform a bigger image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxSs6.png

Right now it looks good but only for certain screen sizes since we're using fixed widths for the ImageView elements. For aligning purposes we've made all of our images the same width, so they can all be aligned properly and only have to worry about the height.

We know that if we want to target any screen size, besides having the proper resources for multiple DPIs, we need to use screen or container related measures, such as match_parent.

Problem is that we can't get match_parent to behave properly on our layout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDOai.png

What are we doing wrong? Any tips for problems like this?

The RelativeLayout code is

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight=".90"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.diapasondev.weatherclothes.WeatherClothesActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/face"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/face"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hands"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/face"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/umbrella"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/neck"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/legs"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feet"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/legs"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For which screen resolution you are facing issue?

Comment: could you share the screen image. I mean the complete image of the screen with marking where you are facing issue.